# class in javascript that will be executed ONLY once (convention)?

Tags: javascript, function, class, modularity, module-pattern

so i have a javascript file with a class

```
var Loader = function(){

    // loader specific code (scoped)

}
```

and i would implement this class in my other js file like this

```
(function()
{

var loaderInstance = new Loader();
// loaderInstance.callApiMethods();

})();
```

So basically this Loader class would be instantiated only once in the entire lifetime of the web application.

Question :

1. Does this Loader really have to be a class
2. any better convention of doing the same.

Comment: In my book of terminology, I tend to refer to singleton-classes that shouldn't have multiple instances as "modules". Maybe that term will help.

Comment: and how it(the term) would help me to prevent Loader to have a class like (instantiable) behaviour

Comment: Ah. Well, it doesn't, that's why I posted as a comment. It seemed like you were describing it as a class in complex terms because you didn't have an exact word for it. Given objects like these aren't really treated like full "classes" much, having a different word for them is helpful I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you are never going to need another loader, you can create it as a literal object (create the instance directly), and export it like any other.

```
var loader = {
    callApiMethods: function(){
        //etc.
    }
}
exports = loader;
```

You can also have a function that programmatically creates an object and returns it, and you can use it as a constructor by passing it whatever arguments you need to at runtime.

```
function loader(x, y, z){
    var obj = {}
    obj.name = x;
    obj.callApiMethods = function(){
        //do something with `y` or `z` etc
    }
    return obj;
}
module.exports = loader;
```

Then you can use the second option like so:

```
var createLoader = require('./filename.js');
//..and then when you need the loader object:
var loaderInstance = createLoader(a,b,c) 
// where a,b,c are any runtime arguments you might need
```

Both those options are theoretically better from a memory management standpoint.

But classes are pretty looking!

Comment: You can also have a function that programmatically creates an object and returns it....code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

1) The loader don't need to be in a class, except if you wanna some scope closure benefit:

Declaring loaderInstance inside a class, make it locally scoped to that class... Otherwise it would be global scoped, and could interfere with other scripts

2) There's other options, but this is the simplest way. Basically a class in javascript is always an object that you could instantiate directly, or assign it to a variable/return with a function, etc, and instantiate it later in the code.

Some other solution could be a framework like backbonejs that force you to have an mvc structure
http://backbonejs.org/